# second parameter in Symfony routing

Tags: php, symfony1, url-routing, symfony-1.4

```
job_show_user:
  url:     /job/:company/:location/:id/:position
  class:   sfDoctrineRoute
  options: { model: JobeetJob, type: object }
  param:   { module: job, action: show }
  requirements:
    id: \d+
    sf_method: [get]
```

in template i use:

```
url_for('job_show_user', $job)
```

earlier (without routing) i used

```
url_for('job/show?id=', $id)
```

how can i make this in routing?

i dont have $job, but i know $id - where this i must redirect.

if i use

```
url_for('job_show_user', 2)
```

then i have error - second parameter must be array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try `url_for('job_show_user', array('id' => 2))`, or `url_for('@job_show_user?id=2')`, but you probably be asked to provide the other parameters too...